# Symfony 5 Doctrine ORM : Get the nearest date from now

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a table profile (p)
and a table founding (f)

each profile can have many founding.
founding have a date field called date_at which represent the date of the founding

I'd like to build a query which will get all the profiles where the last founding (the nearest from now) is egal to ... whatever

Any  idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the fields you want and the most recent date of all profiles (with a join of both tables, and the function max(date)), and then you will have a list to work with.